# Modifying entry display in org-agenda-log-mode agenda view

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

The day view of my org-agenda in org-agenda-log-mode shows the estimated effort for each entry (e.g., the `1:00`, the `0:05`, the `0:45`, etc)---I'd like to remove that if possible. Is there any way to edit what columns are shown in the log mode?

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's controlled by the variable `org-agenda-prefix-format` which has different settings for the agenda, todo, tag and search display. You can find the value with `C-h v org-agenda-prefix-format RET`. E.g. mine is at the default value:

```
((agenda . " %i %-12:c%?-12t% s")
 (todo . " %i %-12:c")
 (tags . " %i %-12:c")
 (search . " %i %-12:c"))
```

If you look at yours, the agenda part should have a `%e` in it: that's what displays the effort and getting rid of that should do what you want. There may be a width and a punctuation char (e.g the `%-12:c` part above says: display the category (%c) in a 12-char wide field, padded with spaces on the right (that's the `-12`) and followed by a colon (that's the `:)).

You can customize the variable: when you hit `C-h org-agenda-prefix-format RET`, you get the description of the variable (which you should read carefully - it is a somewhat complicated variable) as well as its current value, plus you get a link that allows you to customize the variable: that's the easiest way to modify it. In the customize buffer, just edit the format string associated with the agenda and get rid of the %e spec (including the width stuff in between the `%` and the `e`, if any).